# D3 y-axis tick grid opacity and color

Tags: d3.js, opacity, yaxis

I'm working on a voronoi line chart from Bostocks Bl.ock -- https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/8033015 -- and I'm trying to change the opacity and color of the y-axis tick marks. I've stretched the tickSize to (-width) so that they go across the whole chart, but cannot seem to change the stroke from a black to light grey.

Not sure if it's my D3 terminology or a simple class issue.

Here is my current y-axis code:

```
g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
  .ticks(6)
  .tickSize(-width))
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(360)")
  .attr("x", 4)
  .attr("y", 0.5)
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .style("fill", "black")
  .style("font-weight", "bold")
  .text("No. of Tornadoes");
```

Here are my classes:

```
<style>


.axis--y path {
  display: none;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #17BED5;
  stroke-width: 1.0;

}

.cities {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #d73027;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.city--hover {
  stroke: #4575b4;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.focus text {
  text-anchor: middle;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
}

.voronoi path {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.voronoi--show path {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-opacity: 0.2;
}

#form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
}



</style>
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you try adding style to `.axis--y line`? For eg. `.axis--y line { stroke: lightgrey; opacity: 0.3}`

Comment: d3 gives your ticks the class: ticks, so add .ticks path {stroke:lightgray;opacity:0.3} into your css

Comment: They both worked. Thank you much!